# Need help combine my classes together Python

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to create a method that will change User-Agent for urllib2.build_opener()

Thant's what I got so far:

## Crawler.py

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlopener
import re, os

class Crawler():
    def __init__(self):
        # Web site that contains all the browser headers
        self.url = 'http://somewebsite'
        self.opener = urlopener.opener()
        self.web_page=self.opener.open(self.url)
        self.soup=BeautifulSoup(self.web_page.read())
def current_browser(self):
        try:
            web_page=self.opener.open(self.url)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(web_page.read())
            return soup.find(id='uas_textfeld').string
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            print 'ERROR'
```

## urlopener:

```
import cookielib
import urllib, urllib2
import linecache, random

cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+'

def opener():
    #Process Hadlers
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    opener.addheaders=[
                    ('User-Agent', useragent),
                    ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                    ('Accept-Language', 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'),
                    ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
                    ('Keep-Alive', '115'),
                    ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                    ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
                ]
    return opener

#randomly change browser
def browser_change(f_path):
    #f_path is a path to the file that contains browsers
    #To get the file uncoment next lines
    #c=Crawler()
    #c.get_to_the_mobile_browser_list()
    f=open(f_path, 'r+')
    count=0
    for line in f.xreadlines(): count+=1
    br_num=random.randint(1,count)
    useragent=linecache.getline(f_path, br_num)
    return opener()
```

## And That's How I Test Crawler.py:

```
c=Crawler()
print 'Current Browser :\n',c.current_browser()
f_path='/home/vor/mob_brows.txt'
opener=urlopener.browser_change(f_path) # The problem is right here!!!!!
b=Crawler()
print 'New Browser:\n',b.current_browser()
```

And in my output Current Browser and New Browser are the same

```
Current Browser :
Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+
New Browser:
Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+
```

File mob_brows.txt contains information like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC_Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC_Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; zh-tw; HTC Pyramid Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; ko-kr; LG-LU3000 Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC_DesireS_S510e Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile
```

Comment: What I need to change in my code in order to change User Agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `opener` to accept the user agent as an argument...

```
def opener(user_agent):
    #Process Hadlers
    opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    opener.addheaders=[
                    ('User-Agent', user_agent),
                # snip...
                ]
    return opener
```

Then generate a list of openers with different user-agent strings...

```
# this could be nicer, but demonstrates the point
openers = [opener(agent) for agent in open('your_f_path')]
```

Then use `choice` from the random module to pick an opener where you're assigning `self.opener = urlopener.opener()` in your `Crawler` class.

```
from random import choice
use_to_open = choice(openers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is just wrong you will have to remake it at all

Thats how I did my web crawler:

https://github.com/mouuff/MouCrawler/blob/master/moucrawler.py